# Linux router port forwarding using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, router, port-forwarding, iptables

I'm trying to create a port forwarding rule on my linux router, I'm trying the following rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 4242 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.1:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 22 -d 192.168.2.1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

The problem is that when I try to connect from a remote machine, the packet gets dropped by an INPUT rule according to the logs:

```
DROPIN>IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=$source_ip DST=192.168.2.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=61883 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57684 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
DROPIN>IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=$source_ip DST=192.168.2.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=61884 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57684 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

This means that I'm missing an INPUT rule? If I use an INPUT rule wouldn't I open the port globally to the internet?

Here's my whole iptables.sh just in case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PATH='/sbin'

WAN=ppp0
LAN=enp1s0
VLAN10=enp1s0.10
VLAN20=enp1s0.20
VLAN30=enp1s0.30

LAN_NET=192.168.2.0/24
VLAN10_NET=192.168.10.0/24
VLAN20_NET=192.168.20.0/24
VLAN30_NET=192.168.30.0/24

echo "Flushing rules"

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

echo "Allow loopback"
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

echo "Drop invalid states"
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

echo "Allow established and related connections"
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

echo "Rate limit ICMP traffic per source"
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 5/s --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-srcmask 32 --hashlimit-name icmp-echo-drop -j ACCEPT

echo "Allow DHCP"
iptables -I INPUT -i $LAN -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i $VLAN10 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i $VLAN20 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i $VLAN30 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

echo "Allow SSH from LAN"
iptables -A INPUT -i $LAN -s $LAN_NET -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

echo "Allow SSH from VLAN10"
iptables -A INPUT -i $VLAN10 -s $VLAN10_NET -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

echo "Port forward SSH external 4242 to local 22"
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 4242 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.1:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 22 -d 192.168.2.1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

echo "Allow DNS (UDP and TCP for large replies)"
iptables -A INPUT -i $LAN -s $LAN_NET -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $LAN -s $LAN_NET -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $VLAN10 -s $VLAN10_NET -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $VLAN10 -s $VLAN10_NET -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $VLAN20 -s $VLAN20_NET -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $VLAN20 -s $VLAN20_NET -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $VLAN30 -s $VLAN30_NET -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $VLAN30 -s $VLAN30_NET -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

echo "Drop external DNS"
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $LAN -s $LAN_NET -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $LAN -s $LAN_NET -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN10 -s $VLAN10_NET -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN10 -s $VLAN10_NET -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN20 -s $VLAN20_NET -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN20 -s $VLAN20_NET -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN30 -s $VLAN30_NET -p udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN30 -s $VLAN30_NET -p tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP

echo "Drop external DoT"
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $LAN -s $LAN_NET -p tcp --dport 853 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN10 -s $VLAN10_NET -p tcp --dport 853 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN20 -s $VLAN20_NET -p tcp --dport 853 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN30 -s $VLAN30_NET -p tcp --dport 853 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP

echo "Enable network address translation"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $LAN -s $LAN_NET -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN10 -s $VLAN10_NET -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN20 -s $VLAN20_NET -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $VLAN30 -s $VLAN30_NET -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

echo "Enable TCP MSS clamping"
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -o $WAN -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu

echo "Do not reply with Destination Unreachable messages"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j DROP

echo "Log all dropped packets"
iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 1/sec -j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix 'DROPIN>'
iptables -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 1/sec -j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix 'DROPOUT>'
iptables -A FORWARD -m limit --limit 1/sec -j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix 'DROPFWD>'
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an INPUT rule since traffic should flow to another box.

Just to debug, have you tried same rules with -I instead of -A? Does it work that way? 
If so, you should have some general FORWARD rule before, not allowing the particular one.